# Building VC++ 2010 apps for Linux over winelib with winemaker

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2010, winelib

I am preparing to build a VC++ 2010 DLL over winelib in Linux.  I would like to use winemaker to produce the proper makefile from the project's existing .vcxproj file.  But winemaker's (rather non-recent) docs refer only to supporting .dsp and .vcproj files, from the earlier VC++ 2008 installations.  My question is: Does winemaker in Wine 1.6.2 and later support .vcxproj project files, or am I stuck with converting back to a VC++ 2008 project in order to build this and other such Visual Studio 2010 projects for winelib on Linux?

Comment: The whole point of Wine is that it supports any kind of Windows executables -- you don't need special build tools. Just use 2010 (or 2015, join us in the future) and you're set!

Comment: My question is about specific winemaker support for .vcxproj files in Wine version 1.6.2 and later, to produce the necessary makefiles.  I already understand the whole point of Wine, but I want my specific question answered, needed for gcc/g++ software builds.